# Swift - How to Access Model Variables via Case Let

Tags: ios, swift

Requiring some assistance for acquiring a value in json. I want to access the **radioButton** object and access the **description** value (e.g Other Products from Competitors have better product) to assign to tileView.title as shown below:

```
 for viewContent in viewModel.contents {
            switch viewContent {
            case let .radioButtonGroup(radioButtonGroupModel):
                for i in 0..<radioButtonGroupModel.options.count {
                    let tileView = TileRadio()
                    tileView.title = radioButtonGroupModel.options...
```

Printing this **print(radioButtonGroupModel.options[i])** gets:

```
radioButton(RadioButtonModel(description: "Other Products from Competitors have better product", identifier: "competitorReason"))
```

Here's the codebase for json decoder:

```
enum ComponentModel: Decodable {

    case radioButtonGroup(RadioButtonGroupModel)
    case radioButton(RadioButtonModel)
    case emptyComponent

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case radioButtonGroup
        case radioButton
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            switch container.allKeys.first {

            case .radioButtonGroup:
                let value = try container.decode(RadioButtonGroupModel.self, forKey: .radioButtonGroup)
                self = .radioButtonGroup(value)
            case .radioButton:
                let value = try container.decode(RadioButtonModel.self, forKey: .radioButton)
                self = .radioButton(value)
            case .none:
                self = .emptyComponent
            }
        } catch {
            self = .emptyComponent
        }
    }
}

struct RadioButtonGroupModel: Decodable {
    let options: [ComponentModel]
}

struct RadioButtonModel: Decodable {
    let description: String
    let identifier: String
}
```

Here's the partial JSON file:

```
"closureReasons": {
        "pageTitle": "Close account",
        "content": [
 
            {
                "heading": {
                    "title": "Why are you closing this account?"
                }
            },
            {
                "spacing": ".spacing3x"
            },
            {
                "radioButtonGroup": {
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "radioButton": {
                                "identifier": "competitorReason",
                                "description": "Other Products from Competitors have better product"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "radioButton": {
                                "identifier": "betterReason",
                                "description": "I found a better product"
                            }
                        },
```

Any idea on how to retrieve radioButton attributes? Thank you kindly for your help

Comment: How do you know `options` contain only `radioButton`s, and not `emptyComponent`, or another `radioButtonGroup`? After all, a `ComponentModel` can be any one of those 3 cases.

Comment: Hi Sweeper, by using this                                                                                    switch viewContent {
            case let .radioButtonGroup(radioButtonGroupModel).                                     It will differentiate and pinpoint. Options can only contain radioButtons in this context

Comment: So `RadioButtonGroupModel.options` must be an array of `.radioButton`s? You should probably change your JSON format then, if you can, or change how `RadioButtonGroupModel` is decoded, so that `options` is of type `[RadioButtonModel]` instead.

Comment: Yep, I agree. I will change options is of type [RadioButtonModel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` loops can also pattern match with `case let`:

```
for case let .radioButton(radioButtonModel) in radioButtonGroupModel.options {
    print(radioButtonModel.description)
}
```

This loops through all the `ComponentModel`s in `options` that are `.radioButton`s.

Or if you need the index for some reason:

```
for case let (i, .radioButton(radioButtonModel)) in radioButtonGroupModel.options.enumerated() {
    print(i, radioButtonModel.description)
}
```

That said, if `RadioButtonGroupModel.options` can only contain the `.radioButton` case, I'd suggest changing its type to `[RadioButtonModel]` instead, and add some custom decoding logic to decode it:

```
struct RadioButtonGroupModel: Decodable {
    let options: [RadioButtonModel]
    
    enum OptionsCodingKey: String, CodingKey {
        case options
    }
    
    
    enum RadioButtonCodingKey: String, CodingKey {
        case radioButton
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: OptionsCodingKey.self)
        var arrayContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .options)
        var options = [RadioButtonModel]()
        while !arrayContainer.isAtEnd {
            var radioButtonContainer = try arrayContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RadioButtonCodingKey.self)
            if let model = radioButtonContainer.decodeIfPresent(RadioButtonModel.self, forKey: .radioButton) {
                options.append(model)
            }
        }
        self.options = options
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to filter the objects so that they all share the same pattern is bound for each of the enumerated options.

*i.e.*

```swift
switch viewContent.filter {if case ComponentModel. emptyComponent = $0 {return false}; return true} {
```

or you could use `if let` like so:

```swift
if case ComponentModel.radioButtonGroup(let RBGMContent) = radioButtonGroupModel.options[i] {
    print(GMContent)
} else if case ComponentModel.radioButtonGroup(let RBMContent) = radioButtonGroupModel.options[i] {
} else { 
    //this is ComponentModel.emptyComponent
}
```

That being said I would probably use a struct instead of an enum for this, but that's completely up to you.